# Filter Row using Oracle SQL in Multiple Data Rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data for illustration purposes as below:

```
Record_ID | Product | Status
1         | Car     | Active
2         | Car     | Awesome
3         | Truck   | Active
4         | Truck   | Defect
```

I would like to produce the query result as below:

```
Record_ID | Product |
1         | Car     |
```

The Truck is excluded because it has defect information in Record_ID 4

Record ID 2 is excluded because Status "Active" is weighted more than Status "Awesome"

Any chance to return the result with one single Oracle Query?

Thanks!

Comment: I understand about the last row and why it is excluded. But why are the second and third rows also excluded?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. It is because the status active is weighted more than awesome.

Comment: Hi @Hatjhie so if we have only one product with status Awesome it should display in result or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query

```
     select Record_ID,product from
        (
        select Record_ID, product ,row_number() over(partition by product order by Record_ID ) as r_no
        from ss
        where product not  in (select product from ss where status='Defect'))
        where R_no=1
```

Comment: if we have only one product with status Awesome it should display in result or not? based on that i will alter the above query.

Comment: Thank you! I got the inspiration on how to solve the actual problem.

Comment: If the sample data had the `RECORD_ID` (or `STATUS`) for the first two rows swapped then this would not return the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Using only a single table scan:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f92d/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Product_Statuses ( Record_ID, Product, Status ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'Car',      'Active'  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Car',      'Awesome' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Truck',    'Active'  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'Truck',    'Defect'  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'Airplane', 'Awesome' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT MIN( Record_ID ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DECODE( Status, 'Active', 1, 'Awesome', 2, 3 ) ) AS Record_ID,
       MIN( Status )    KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DECODE( Status, 'Active', 1, 'Awesome', 2, 3 ) ) AS Status
FROM   Product_Statuses
GROUP BY Product
HAVING SUM( DECODE( Status, 'Defect', 1, 0 ) ) = 0
ORDER BY RECORD_ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f92d/2/0)**:

```
| RECORD_ID |  STATUS |
|-----------|---------|
|         1 |  Active |
|         5 | Awesome |
```